# Estrutura de dados eficiente para problema concorrente de high scores

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados, concorrência

Como parte de um teste foi pedido que eu desenvolvesse uma aplicação para gerir dados de *high scores* em ambientes com alta concorrência. Essa aplicação não deve persistir nada em disco ou utilizar bibliotecas e *frameworks* externos. Basicamente os requisitos dizem que:

- otimizar o uso de memória e CPU é importantíssimo
- o serviço receberá um número estelar de *requests* simultâneos
- para a parte de http devemos utilizar a classe [HttpServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html).

A aplicação é basicamente um conjunto de serviços rest para o usuário:

- logar (deve retornar um token e manter o user autenticado por 10 minutos)
- postar um *high score* para determinado nível
- obter uma lista de *high scores* para determinado nível (em ordem)

O sistema só deve retornar 15 *high scores* para cada nível, os *high scores* são únicos para cada par Usuário / Nível (ou seja, para a fase x o user y só deve possuir um *high score*).

Considerando os requisitos funcionais e não funcionais pensei na seguinte estrutura de dados para armazenar *high scores* (com o mínimo de retenção):

```java
// Mapa que liga um nivel a uma lista ordenada de High Scores
private static final Map<Integer, ConcurrentSkipListSet<HighScore>> scores = 
   new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
// Conjunto de usuários autenticados
private static final Set<AuthToken> authorized = 
   Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<AuthToken, Boolean>());
```

Enquanto essa estrutura de dados me parece eficiente no sentido de reduzir a retenção não sei o quanto ela acaba desperdiçando memória internamente.

Da mesma maneira, os `ConcurrentSkipListSet` permitem inserção ordenada em `log(n)` e tornam a implementação do método que retorna *high scores* trivial. 
Por outro lado, para limitar o `Set` aos top 15 *high scores*  por nível (para evitar desperdício de memória e *crashes*), fiz uma verdadeira ginástica incluindo o uso de [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) para contar a quantidade de *high scores* por nível (o método `size` da `ConcurrentSkipListSet` é custoso) e a necessidade de sincronizar vários pontos com *locks*.

Em suma, não estou convencido de que estou usando a estratégia mais eficiente para resolver o problema e nem estou acostumado a pensar em tão baixo nível...

No mundo "real" resolveria esse problema de maneira trivial com o uso de um *container* [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), um Servlet para o login armazendo a autenticação na sessão e, provavelmente, um banco de dados *embedded* como o [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). Infelizmente não estou autorizado a usar nada disso.

Dessa maneira, como vocês abordariam um problema desse tipo dadas as *constraints* artificias de tecnologia? Usariam quais estruturas de dados (ou desenvolveriam suas próprias?)? A minha estratégia é "boa o suficiente" para o problema ou viajei na solução?

---

**P.S.** [Esse problema](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24740/java-http-server-and-multi-threading-optimization) submetido à *Code Review* se parece muito com o que estou resolvendo (e a solução foi parecida com a minha também).

Comment: Suponho que esteja fora do seu escopo um caso em que o mesmo usuário submeta um *high score* **menor** que um outro submetido anteriormente, certo? (mesmo porque isso não faria sentido...) Da mesma forma, um score submetido não pode ser removido, certo? (pergunto pra saber se você pode mesmo seguramente descartar o 16º resultado pra frente)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, exatamente. Um único _score_ por usuário / nível (o maior) e não existe nenhum front para apagar um _high-score_. Podemos seguramente descartar resultados além do décimo quinto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tenho muita experiência com programação concorrente - em particular envolvendo Java - então não posso te sugerir uma estrutura de dados eficiente, mas posso te dar alguns parâmetros para te ajudar a decidir:

1. Não se preocupe com a ordem de complexidade da estrutura, mas sim com seu fator constante.

   Você diz que o "`ConcurrentSkipListSet` permite inserção ordenada em `log(n)`", mas isso é mesmo relevante em uma lista com apenas 15 elementos? Imagina quantos nós essa lista vai criar? (lembre-se que um objeto Java tem um *overhead* fixo de uns `24 bytes` se me lembro bem, mais uma referência pro `HighScore` no mínimo e outras referências internas para os demais nós) E as falhas na predição de desvio? (*branch prediction*) Não que eu ache isso relevante, uma vez que o gargalo dos processadores modernos não é o CPU, mas a cache...

   Um simples `array` (ou o equivalente *thread-safe* disponível) com referências para os `HighScore`s ocuparia menos espaço (*overhead* de `24 bytes` + 4 ou 8 bytes por cada uma das 15 referências). E o desempenho para percorrê-lo seria bom, ainda que ele estivesse desordenado (basta percorrê-lo todo lembrando do menor índice, depois acrescentar ou substituir o menor conforme o total seja menor ou igual  a 15) - principalmente porque as referências ocuparão uma posição contígua na memória (o que evita *cache miss*). Se a solução envolver uma seção crítica (`synchronize`), então pouco importa o algoritmo, pois o *lock* sozinho vai ser responsável por 90% do tempo de execução. Por falar nisso...
2. O `synchronize` é seu pior inimigo.

   De novo, não tenho familiaridade com os recursos que Java oferece para acesso concorrente, mas se for o caso que esse `ConcurrentSkipListSet` consegue operar sem usar `synchronize` então é melhor utilizá-lo do que fazer qualquer "gambiarra" para poder acessar o `size` em tempo constante. Esse método só é "custoso" se o seu conjunto é grande, mas `log(n)` numa lista de 15 elementos é quase o mesmo que `O(1)`.

   Estabelecer uma seção crítica **sempre** envolve o acesso ao disco (uns `10.000` ciclos de CPU da última vez que eu chequei), por isso evite o uso de `synchronize` sempre que isso for possível. A propósito...
3. Não é necessário esperar que uma operação esteja pronta antes de terminar o *request*.

   Quando o usuário submete seu *high score*, sugiro "enfileirá-lo" para processamento e seguir em frente. Dê uma olhada em [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) por exemplo. Se você tiver um *thread* dedicado em reunir todos os *high scores* submetidos (i.e. cada *request* **produz** algo, um *thread* à parte **consome**) fica mais fácil escolher estruturas de dados que ofereçam bom desempenho sem precisar usar um *lock*.

   Se logo depois de submeter um *high score* o usuário pedir a lista para um determinado nível, você sempre pode pegar uma cópia daquela lista (é recomendável que o *thread* apenas a atualize de forma atômica), se necessário atualizá-la com os últimos scores ainda não processados (`ConcurrentLinkQueye.toArray(T[] a)`) e retornar. Se quiser evitar esse retrabalho - e não houver problema em ocasionalmente se obter uma lista desatualizada (inevitável) que **não inclua** o último score que o **próprio usuário postou** (evitável, mas traz mais complexidade) - apenas retorne a lista no seu estado atual.

No mais, creio que sua solução proposta está adequada. Na prática eu sugeriria que em vez de um conjunto de *tokens* de acesso, você mapeasse um *token* para um usuário (para evitar que um usuário atualizasse o *high score* de outro), mas se você estivesse preocupado com trapaça nada que você fizesse seria 100% garantido... (uma vez que os dados vêm do lado cliente)